# Cannot switch Python with pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

I would like to use `pyenv` to switch python2 and python3.

I successfully downloaded python2 and python3 and pyenv with following code.

```
brew install pyenv

brew install pyenv-virtualenv

pyenv install 2.7.10

pyenv install 3.5.0
```

However, I cannot switch from python2 to python3..

```
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ pyenv global
2.7.10
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.10 (set by /Users/Soma/.pyenv/version)
  3.5.0
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ pyenv global 3.5.0
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ pyenv global
3.5.0
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.10
* 3.5.0 (set by /Users/Soma/.pyenv/version)
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$
```

I do not understand why this happens.

My python is in this directory.

```
Soma-Suzuki:~ Soma$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You can just edit your .bashrc file. Make alias python=Python3.5.0

Comment: @AnakinTung thus totally defeating proper version control.

Comment: do you have a ".python-version" file in that directory?

Answer (score 321):

**[July 2021]**
If you see this message when running `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

```sh
WARNING: `pyenv init -` no longer sets PATH.
Run `pyenv init` to see the necessary changes to make to your configuration.
```

you should check the message from `pyenv init` as the warning says, but in a nutshell, you can use `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` instead.

And don't forget to accordingly update your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or the like if necessary.

Comment: This solved my issue on Mac OS Catalina. I wasn't getting that warning, and my Python version wasn't updating despite having `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in my `.zshrc`. Thanks!

Comment: I was NOT getting the warning, nor anybody in the class I was teaching, but was super frustrating ... Not happy that I never saw a headsup about this change.

Comment: For macOS Big Sur (installed via brew), I needed (as well as my existing `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in `.zshrc`) to add the following to `.zprofile`: `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`.

Comment: What's the difference between `-` and `--path`?

Comment: Like ScrotumDave I also couldn't generate the warning on Catalina, but this fixed it anyway.

Comment: This also solved my issue on Mac Monterey

Answer (score 213):

Try this: `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`

Example:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.9
mac:~ $ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
mac:~ $ python -V
Python 3.5.0
```

More info:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: Per the documentation given, place `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` toward the end of `.bash_profile`. Note that for me, placing it in `.bashrc` did *not* work. (The docs warn about "strange" behavior if `.bashrc` is used.)

Comment: Running `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` doesn't change the `python -V` in my case, even though I do have the pyenv versions installed in `~/.pyenv`

Comment: I was missing `export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"` in `.zshrc` in addition of the `export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"` I had configured

Comment: and finally don't forget to restart your shell so the path changes take effect `$ exec "$SHELL"`

Comment: As Vadorequest said, if pyenv is installed using homebrew, you have to add $PYENV_ROOT/shims to the path as $PYENV_ROOT/bin does not exist. I think that is unique to homebrew installs of pyenv.

Comment: Not sure why, but on my system $PYENV_ROOT was never defined; adding `export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH"` to my .zshrc file worked.

Comment: None of this works for me unfortunately

Comment: none of this works. 1) add `export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"` to `~/.bash_profile`; 2) `source ~/.bash_profile`; 3) `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`; 4) `python -V`; 5) output: python 2.7.16 booooooooo

Comment: Adding export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH" along with the other ones to my .zshrc that I had to find online because the installer didn't list them, worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 92):

In ubuntu the  `~/.bashrc` file needs to be updated and change `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`  to  `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`.

*Edit*: Just to point out that the change will be in effect after  restarting the terminal. If you do not want to restart the terminal you can also do an extra step **in addition** to changing the file. In the terminal execute the same command you changed in the file: `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`

Comment: This was the solution for me on MacOs as well. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only fix worked for me (Pop OS).

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: The works like charm for me on MacOS as well, thanks a million :)

Comment: wow "restart the machine" ?? why not just start a new shell session?

Comment: Other than this weird "restart" suggestion, adding the  '--path'  parameter actually did the job.

Comment: @jsbueno the file is loaded when the terminal starts no? This is why I suggested the extra step to make it work in the current terminal.

Comment: yes. restarting the terminal - that is quite different from restarting the whole machine. Thanks for editing!

Comment: What is the solution for Windows 10?

Answer (score 72):

For me, this worked on MacOS with ZSH after installing via Homebrew:

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
```

I initially had `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` inside of my `~/.zshrc` file, but that didn't seem to work.
After following this guide: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout I remved the `eval` call from the `.zshrc` file and added it to the `.zprofile` file using the above command and after restarting terminal everything worked.

Comment: In my case this there wasn't a ~/.zprofile file and ~/.zshrc didn't mention pyenv at all so I just ran `echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zshrc` and it worked.

Comment: `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` in `~/.zshrc` could be the root cause.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. Cheers

Comment: Finally a working solution!

Answer (score 35):

You forgot to add this `eval "$(pyenv init -)"`.

Add this to your .bash_profile or .bashrc file (mac <=10.14) or to your .zshrc file (mac 10.15+)

Comment: per the documentation it should be towards the end of the file

Comment: @Jonathan no different

Comment: Enter ```pyenv init``` in Terminal to see if there are some necessary changes to be made.

Comment: @xemexpress that's not super helpful, for me it just tells me to "See the README" ... somewhere ...

Answer (score 29):

This is a great opportunity to learn about how pyenv works under the hood.

The `pyenv global` command simply reads the data in your `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/version` directory.  It's basically the same as `cat /Users/Soma/.pyenv/version`.

The `pyenv versions` command is just [checking through the hierarchy](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version) and selecting the right Python version to use when a "shim interceptable" command like `python` or `pip` is run.

When you run `pyenv global 3.5.0`, the `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/version` file is updated to contain "3.5.0".  That's the only change pyenv makes.  Most users are surprised that `pyenv global 3.5.0` only changes a single line in a text file!

When you run `python --version`, your Terminal will perform the same steps it performs when any shell command is executed: it goes through each directory in your `PATH` and looks for the first executable named `python`.

If you type `echo $PATH`, you'll have something like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Your machine is finding the `python` executable in the `/usr/bin` directory.

You can add this code to your `~/.bash_profile` file to change your PATH.

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Restart your terminal, run `echo $PATH` again, and you'll now see output like this: `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Notice how the `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/shims` directory is at the start of the `PATH` now.  When you run `python --version` now, the command will be handled by the `python` executable in `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/shims`.  The command won't have an opportunity to be picked up by `/usr/bin/python` because it'll be grabbed by `/Users/Soma/.pyenv/shims/python` first.

I can see why this bug confuses you.  It's hard to debug this unless you know [how pyenv works](https://mungingdata.com/python/how-pyenv-works-shims/).

Comment: I have tried your solution but still it is using (system version of python), I use echo $PATH within activated environment and it showed this ```/home/nikhil/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/nikhil/.pyenv/bin:/home/nikhil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin```  and then I use (python3 -V) and it showed me my system python version, then I tried to know the python path and it was ```/usr/local/bin/python3```

Comment: So I solved my problem with your and @Joey Iglesias answer, your answer helped me to understand the working of pyenv. If anyone wants to know how I solve this then please check my comment under his answer.

Comment: @NikhilBhardwaj Thanks, combining the solutions by Powers and JoeyIglesias is the way to go. It seems to be a specific issue with the M1 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 24):

I have struggled with the same issue on an Apple M1 MacBook Pro running Monterey with Pyenv installed on a Rosetta emulation terminal.

My solution was to add the following to my ~/.zshrc file:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

I added nothing to ~/.zprofile.

I can now see the versions switching as expected.

Comment: After adding both lines it worked, before I was adding only the first line. Also the problem with my configuration was that I was getting ```/home/nikhil/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:``` virtualenv shims only but NOT PYENV SHIMS, so after adding that second line now I'm getting ```/home/nikhil/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/nikhil/.pyenv/shims:``` PYENV SHIMS also. To get that location write ```echo $PATH```. Also @Powers answer also helped me

Comment: Thanx, this helped me with my o-my-zsh terminal

Comment: this also worked for me. macbook m1, brew, ohmyzsh, without virtualenv-init, it worked for version switching and virtualenv setting as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

MacOSX 10.15.17

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Add or update

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Then run

```
source  ~/.zshrc

pyenv global 3.7.0
```

finally run

```
python -V
Python 3.7.0 (default, Dec 12 2021, 13:40:24)
```

Comment: Thanx, this helped me with my o-my-zsh terminal

Comment: This worked at MacOs Big Sur

Answer (score 13):

##### Background

- now: `20210926`
- Mac: `10.15.7`
- pyenv: `2.0.7`

##### Solution

###### for current console

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

###### for work after every boot

if you want auto take effect after Mac boot, then add it to you boot script

here my is zsh, so:

```sh
vi ~/.zshrc
```

add

`eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`

done.

Comment: So this worked for me on Ubuntu by adding it to my bashrc file -- fixed the pyenv global command, but I don't see this anywhere in the pyenv documentation to add that line: `eval "$(pyenv init --path)` ? Or did I miss it? What does that line actually do?

Comment: This also works in WSL2 Arch. The original pyenv installation adds ```$(pyenv init -)``` to ```~/.zshrc``` which did not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Run `pyenv init` and do exactly what it tells you to do.
For me, the solution was adding the following to `.profile`:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

**And** also adding this line to `.bashrc`:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Don't forget to restart your shell.  (Close and reopen or `exec "$SHELL"`)

Answer (score 8):

[ November 2021 ]

This is what fixed the issue for me on Mac OSX with ZSH. pyenv does a bad job about explaining what needs to be added to the zsh config. $PYENV_ROOT was not defined. Order is important.

Add this near the top of your ~/.zshrc config:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
PYENV_ROOT=$(pyenv root)
```

Comment: This worked for me with zsh on Ubuntu LTS 20.04 running on Windows 10.

Comment: yup, that was the additional bits i needed, too.  thanks @ianSmith!

Comment: Aren't the two lines in the wrong order? `PATH` uses parameter substitution using environment variable (`PYENV_ROOT`) that's defined after the substitution takes place.

Comment: pyenv can't be found until the path is made.

Answer (score 8):

Run `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` (note the quotes) in the Terminal on Mac OS to add Pyenv shims directory to PATH. Then run `pyenv global 3.5.0` again and check with `python3 --version`.

Answer (score 7):

Just FYI, if your executable has been found EARLIER than the pyenv's shim location then you will not be able to change python version when you type `python` in your shell.

To use pyenv properly, shim directory should be the very first thing in your PATH variable. For example,

if your PATH looks like

```
/usr/bin:/home/kenobi/.pyenv/shims:...
```

And if you have a python executable in `/usr/bin`, you will not be able to use pyenv properly. You should arrange your PATH configuration in `~/.bashrc` like below

```
/home/kenobi/.pyenv/shims:/usr/bin:...
```

Then restart your shell and you'll be fine.
For me, I had these lines in my `~/.zshrc`

```
# PyEnv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"  # This line was causing the problem
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

# Docker
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```

As you can see, I had `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` after pyenv configuration lines. Then I solved the issue by switching the blocks like below

```
# Docker
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH  # Not a problem anymore.
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock

# PyEnv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Comment: For me the problem was that a package installed another python version as a dependency and screwed my pyenv. Doing this will ensure that the same problem will not affect me again.

Answer (score 6):

After running `brew install pyenv` it's good to reference the OG docs on setting up your shell environment from the `pyenv` github README:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv

As of version 2.3.0 and zsh, the following should be run

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 5):

Check your `PATH`. Somehow I have `.pyenv/bin`, when it should be `.pyenv/shims`.

Fix the path with `export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH"` (and add to zshrc etc).

Comment: Just in case: to check your path: `$ echo $PATH`

Answer (score 4):

In the initial question I see `MacOS` and `Pyenv` installed with `Homebrew`. For the `shell` I assume is `Zsh` so one should have:

into file `~/.zprofile` this following line

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

And into file `~/.zshrc` this following line

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Make sure that your terminal app runs the shell as a login shell.

For other versions I suggest to see [README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md) and [post-installation steps](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout)

Comment: Thanks, this line `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` is exactly what i have been missing

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only for people that are using Fish shell and find this thread. Pyenv uses shims, [ref](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#understanding-shims), so in order to make pyenv work with your fish shell you have to edit your ~/.config/fish/config.fish file an append the pyen shim directory at the beginning of your $PATH variable. Here is what my config.fish looks like.

```
### PATH ###
set default_path /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /bin /sbin
set macports /opt/local/bin
set androiddev ~/Android\ Development/platform-tools/
set rbenv ~/.rbenv/shims/
set pyenv ~/.pyenv/shims/
set anaconda /Users/m4punk/anaconda/bin/
set pg_config /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/


### Virtual Enviroment Wrapper ###

set -g VIRTUALFISH_HOME ~/Documents/Coding/python/virtualenvs
set -g VIRTUALFISH_DEFAULT_PYTHON /usr/local/bin/python3
eval (python -m virtualfish)

### NVM Settings ###
set -g NVM_DIR ~/.nvm

set -gx PATH $pyenv $default_path $macports $androiddev $rbenv $pg_config

setenv EDITOR sublime
```

The relevant lines here are

```
set pyenv ~/.pyenv/shims/
```

and

```
set -gx PATH $pyenv $default_path $macports $androiddev $rbenv $pg_config
```

The first creates a variable for the pyenv shim path, the second adds it to the front of your path variable. Just save&close, restarted your terminal session and you should be all set.

Comment: it shouldnt be this hard to switch python versions with pyenv, isn't that the purpose of pyenv? Nevertheless painfully difficult to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

There are situation where one cannot update `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` because the machine is shared. In that case adding `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to the bash script should still work, because `pyenv init` adds the path to pyenv shims to the $PATH. e.g., pyenv will execute a command like this:

```
export PATH="/path/to/.pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
```

Hope this explains why it is working. Alternatively, one should be able to just export the `/path/to/.pyenv/shims` in their bash script and it should enable `pyenv` to switch python versions.

I was also facing a situation where `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` indeed helped switch python version to 3.8.8. But when I started a virtual environment, the python version inside the virtual environment creation would fail:

```
virtualenv "$VENV_PATH" -p 3.8.8

RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.8.8'
```

But with `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` the virtual environment also got the 3.8.8. version of `python`.

Answer (score 2):

I installed pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv with brew too and had the same issue.

It's easy to solve after you know exactly what to do:

1- You need to know what shell interpreter you are using. Direct quoting from the https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

> By default, your Mac uses either zsh or bash as the command-line
> interpreter for the login shell and interactive shell:
>
> - zsh (Z shell) is the default shell for all newly created user accounts, starting with macOS Catalina.
> - bash is the default shell in macOS Mojave and earlier.

And of course, each interpreter is using different files for environment variables, like PATH, JAVA_HOME etc.
bash is using $HOME/.bash_profile and $HOME/.bashrc, while zsh is using $HOME/.zprofile and $HOME/.zshrc

2- After installing pyenv and installing the python version which you want to use (e.g. pyenv install 3.y), open the /.bash_profile or /.zprofile file wrt your interpreter.

**Note1:** I'm using bash interpreter and my $HOME/.bashrc file is empty. So I don't know what happens whether any PATH declaration in the /.bashrc would affect the /.bash_profile declarations or not. You may need to check this.

3- pyenv creates $HOME/.pyenv/shims directory and uses this to switch python versions that you installed.

So you just need to add the following line to the bottom (not necessarily to the very bottom of the file. You just need to go to the end of all PATH declarations.)

```
export PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/shims:$PATH
```

**Note2:** "$HOME/.pyenv/shims" MUST be at the beginning of the PATH variable. Because all the paths are read from left to right order by the interpreter. So be careful adding new paths to the PATH variable in the future.

**Note3:** There are two commands that sets python version. One is "pyenv global #python_version_here#" and the other is "pyenv local #python_version_here#". Under a directory, hierarchically "local"  command is top of "global" one. So, if you run the "local" command under $HOME directory, you cannot change the global python version with the "global" command. In that case, either
1- You can continue to use "local" command under the $HOME directory
2- Delete $HOME/.python-version file and return to "global" setting

This is my shell output to show this hierarchy:

```
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv global system  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv versions  
* system (set by /Users/ozgurcengelli/.pyenv/version) #look the path  
  3.6.15  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv local system  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv versions  
* system (set by /Users/ozgurcengelli/.python-version) #look the path  
  3.6.15  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv global 3.6.15  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv versions  
* system (set by /Users/ozgurcengelli/.python-version) #look the path  
  3.6.15  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ rm $HOME/.python-version  
Ozgurs-MacBook-Pro:~ ozgurcengelli$ pyenv versions  
  system  
* 3.6.15 (set by /Users/ozgurcengelli/.pyenv/version) #look the path
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and ended up making some changes to the ***way*** `pyenv init` goes about setting up the shell but in the end it works the same.  The only real difference from the [guide](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#advanced-configuration) on the pyenv github page is that I had to add the `$(pyenv root)/bin` directory to my path too.

The reason I did this was to avoid long shell startup times from running `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` and all the other `.bash_profile` work that goes into my local shell environment.  Just to be clear; Pyenv itself doesn't create a bad shell experience, in my humble opinion, but when you work with several languages that all have their own version management systems and tools that like to be initialized from the .profile *with* `pyenv`, etc., the shell initialization process can get slow.

**Here's the steps I took to set myself up, at a high view:**

1. Run the dry-run version of the `pyenv init` command so you can see
   what it would have done for you.
2. Put the `PATH` and shell environment vars into your `.bash_profile`
   (or whatever file your distro uses).
3. Put the function `pyenv init` printed into your `.bashrc` and source your `.bashrc`
   from your `.bash_profile`

This is one way to get it done but it's better to use this as "pseudo-code".  You should exchange `.bash_profile` for whatever file your distro prefers.

```
$ pyenv init - # use the output for reference, it doesn't actually do anything
$ cat <<EOBP > ~/.bash_profile
export PYENV_SHELL=bash
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$(pyenv root)/bin:$PATH
[ -f  /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.9/completions/pyenv.bash ] && . /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.9/completions/pyenv.bash
[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc
EOBP
```

The next bit updates your shell with a new bit of logic that we copied from the `pyenv init` dry run from step 1, above.

```
$ cat <<EORC > ~/.bashrc
# from $(pyenv init -)
pyenv() {
    local command
    command="${1:-}"
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift
    fi

    case "$command" in
    rehash|shell)
        eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
    *)
        command pyenv "$command" "$@";;
    esac
}
EORC
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing the correct version, close all terminals and try pyenv global 3.7.2 then try python --version, it should work

Answer (score 1):

If the Readme here doesn't work:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Double check if you've set path before manually. In my case I added alias to old python in my .zshrc file and after removing it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're MacOS user...

Run

```
pyenv init
```

to get this tip:

```
# See the README for instructions on how to set up
# your shell environment for Pyenv.
```

So, go to https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme to get this tip:

> For Zsh:
>
> MacOS, if Pyenv is installed with Homebrew:

```
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> ~/.zprofile
 
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

> Make sure that your terminal
> app runs the shell as a login shell.

Works for me with **macOS Monterey 12.0.1** and **pyenv 2.2.0**.
**Pyenv** installed with **brew** and **python** installed with `pyenv install`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers [***by @Powers***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61175110/10237506) and [***by @Boby***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820026/10237506) actually helped steer me in the right direction, albeit in a roundabout way.

In my case, I tried everything, including: upgrading/installing pyenv with brew using `brew upgrade pyenv`, adding config for pyenv to my `~/.zshrc` file, then removing it from there and adding it to `~/.zprofile`, and basically everything in between.

The problem was that when I activated a particular Python version that I had installed, such as:

```
pyenv global 3.6.15
```

It didn't actually work. When I typed `python` in a terminal, it still showed my **system** Python version, which was different (3.11)

Long story short, I eventually happened upon the fix rather unintentionally, when I was in the midst of updating my `~/.zprofile` based on another answer, and then opening up a new terminal window to test out whether that fixed or resolved the issue.

I noticed a peculiar strangeness, in that under my user home `~` directory, the Python version was 3.6 correctly (as set in pyenv) but when I `cd`-ed into the folder I was having trouble with, it gave me a different python version when I ran `python`.

So, thus confused and rendered rather speechless, I ran the following command on my terminal from within this folder:

```
$ ls -la
```

And lo and behold, what I did I get other than:

```
drwxr-xr-x  37 usr  staff   1184 Mar 23 17:14 .
drwxr-x---+ 94 usr  staff   3008 Mar 30 16:01 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 usr  staff  16388 Mar 13 11:17 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 usr  staff      7 Feb 10 18:10 .python-version
-rw-r--r--@  1 usr  staff    170 Feb  9  ?     Other stuff
```

Aha! The culprit (in my case) was the `.python-version` file.

I `cat`ed it, and found the contents of the file was just plainly:

```
system
```

Cleaning up by deleting the file, by running:

```
rm .python-version
```

Resolved the issue in my case.

FYI, it looks like this is a trickle-down effect, so that if I had a `.python-version` file under:

```
~/git-repos
```

Then the same settings (overriding Python version for `pyenv`) applies to any children sub-folders, such as:

```
~/git-repos/my-repo
```

Solution, was to entirely remove any `.python-version` files, all the way up to (and potentially including) the user home or `~` directory on my Mac OS.

Hope this helps someone else, who ends up in the same boat or situation as me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done `pyenv local` at any time in the past, it will create a new `.python_version` file in your home directory ~.

If your development environment is not configured properly, that could affect the pyenv global command.

Remove this file and `pyenv global` should work.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked. It looks like I didn't follow the correct installation process. I solve it by doing the below:

1. Go into ~/.zshrc
2. Add `alias brew='env PATH="${PATH//$(pyenv root)\/shims:/}" brew'` at the end of the file
3. Run `pyenv init`

More about this in [the pyenv docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md#homebrew-in-macos)

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually.
Change the path within your `~/.zprofile`

```
vim ~/.zprofile
```

```
 PATH="/Users/you-user-name/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin:${PATH}"
 export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who gets this error in the future.

In my case it was related to an extra directory created inside `~/.pyenv/versions` folder.

I was not able to change my python version to 3.10.11. And the reason was this extra directory which looked like: `~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.11\ /`. Looking into the contents of this dir weren't useful so tried removing it and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This is a constant issue for me and none of these answers have worked. I've found that when I check pyenv versions, it will say:

```
Python 3.9.6(version set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

I just unset that environment variable and that solves the issue.

Comment: how did you unset that environment variable?

Comment: X is your variable so, unset X or set -e X