# Pyenv cannot switch Python versions

Tags: pyenv

I have pyenv installed, however, it does not do its most basic function, namely switch Python versions.  The following terminal commands demonstrate this.

```
the file `main.py` is equivalent to:
import sys
print (sys.version)

Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:kylefoley kylefoley$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.14 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
  3.5.3
  3.6.1
  3.7.3
  pypy3.6-7.1.1
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:kylefoley kylefoley$ pyenv global 3.5.3
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:kylefoley kylefoley$ pyenv exec python main.py
2.7.14 (default, Oct 17 2019, 00:01:43)
```

As you can see when I run `main.py` the version that comes out is 2.7.  A lot of people have this problem.  One common solution is putting

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

On the bash_profile which I have done and that did not help. Over here
[Cannot switch Python with pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321312/cannot-switch-python-with-pyenv)
it is recommended:

> Put the PATH and shell environment vars into your .bash_profile (or whatever file your distro uses).

But what PATH and what shell environment vars is he talking about?

Also my `.bashrc` file looks like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/kylefoley/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Any help would be appreciated.  One other things, when I run the following commands, I get the following output:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:kylefoley kylefoley$ python
Python 3.6.1rc1 (default, Mar  4 2017, 22:58:58)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.bashrc` is not `source`d in a **non-login** mode.

Init files for Bash:

- **login mode**:

  - `/etc/profile`
  - `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
- interactive **non-login**:

  - `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
  - `~/.bashrc`
- **non-interactive**:

  - source file in `$BASH_ENV`

And on macOS, the default Bash shell opened by a terminal app is a interactive login shell, but on Linux, the default shell opened by a terminal app is a interactive non-login shell.

### Solution

The weird interactive, non-login loading requirement confuses people in other situations as well. The **best solution** is to change the loading requirement of `~/.bashrc` as **interactive only**, which is exactly most of the Linux distros are doing.

```
# write content below into ~/.bash_profile

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This should be the solution you desire. And I recommend every Bash user setup this in the profile.

### References

- [Unix shell initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)

Comment: I was trying to launch pyenv with aliases set in the bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was done correctly, it's just that I thought the terminal command `. ~/.bash_profile` updates the bash profile without having to close the terminal or open a new one in order for changes to take effect. It turns out that `. ~/.bash_profile` only updates some of the bash_profile.  After restarting the terminal, everything was working as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your .bashrc or similar file, the line.

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

After the `"export PATH=$PYENV..."` . Don't forget to reset your terminal after try again!
Worked on Fedora & Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this into you .bashrc file:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"
```

If your `.bashrc` is sourced from `~/.bash_profile` you are done.

Official docs https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#advanced-configuration suggests puting into .bashrc:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

which was not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

1.) configure:

```
pyenv global [python version]
```

2.)restart terminal (close all terminal windows)