# Pyenv doesn't change python version when 'pyenv global 3.7.2'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv

I'm using Ubuntu 16.4

I installed  dependencies for pyvenv and pyenv ,

by

```
su sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential  libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev  wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev  xz-utils tk-dev git python-pip
```

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

in ~/.bashrc

and I ran

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

run the

```
pyenv install 3.7.2
pyenv global 3.7.2
```

and pyenv versions shows

```
 system
* 3.7.2 (set by PYENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

but python -V shows is just same as my system python

```
Python 3.5.2
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with
[Cannot switch Python with pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321312/cannot-switch-python-with-pyenv)

I added
`export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PATH"`
in my ~/.profile .

Really Thanks